# Simplify summation of factorials

Tags: summation, factorial

Hello I guess this equality is true but I don't know how to solve it.

$$\sum_{x=0}^{m(1-\text{sel})} (m-1-x)! (m \cdot \text{sel}) \frac{(m(1-\text{sel}))!}{(m(1-\text{sel})-x)!}(x+1) = \frac{(m+1)!}{1+m \cdot \text{sel}}$$

Comment: What is meaning of $sel$

Comment: @AdiDani: I assumed that $m\cdot sel=n$ and everything works out fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that $sel=\frac{n}{m}$, then
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^{m-n}(m-1-k)!n\frac{(m-n)!}{(m-n-k)!}(k+1)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m-n}\binom{m-1-k}{n-1}(m-n)!n!(k+1)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m-n}\binom{m-1-k}{n-1}(m-n)!n!((m+1)-(m-k))\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m-n}\binom{m-1-k}{n-1}(m+1)(m-n)!n!\\
&-\sum_{k=0}^{m-n}\binom{m-k}{n}n(m-n)!n!\\
&=\binom{m}{n}(m+1)(m-n)!n!\\
&-\binom{m+1}{n+1}n(m-n)!n!\\
&=\binom{m}{n}(m+1)(m-n)!n!\\
&-\binom{m}{n}(m+1)(m-n)!n!\frac{n}{n+1}\\
&=\binom{m}{n}(m+1)(m-n)!n!\frac1{n+1}\\
&=\frac{(m+1)!}{n+1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you tell me which rules do you use to solve this passage (from 4 to 5) :$$
=\sum_{k=0}^{m-n}\binom{m-1-k}{n-1} = \binom{m}{n}\\
$$

Comment: @Francesco: The general rule is
$$
\sum_{j=m}^{n-k}\binom{n-j}{k}\binom{j}{m}=\binom{n+1}{k+m+1}
$$
If we use $m=0$, we get the particular rule I used
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-j}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}
$$

Comment: @robjohn Good job! I didn't think about setting "sel" to a fraction.

Answer (score 0):

If $N$ is a non-negative integer, then the $N$th rising power of $x$ is defined
as the following product of $N$ factors: $x^\overline{N}=x(x+1)\cdots(x+N-1)$. 
For a positive integer $K$, the calculus of rising powers gives
$$\sum_{k=1}^K k^\overline{N}={K^\overline{N+1}\over N+1}.$$

Therefore, if $M\leq N$ are non-negative integers 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{x=0}^M {(N-x)!\over (M-x)!}(x+1) 
&=& \sum_{j=0}^M \sum_{x=j}^M  {(N-x)!\over (M-x)!}\\[5pt]
&=& \sum_{j=0}^M \sum_{k=1}^{M+1-j} k^\overline{N-M} \\[5pt]
&=& {\sum_{j=0}^M (M+1-j)^\overline{N-M+1}\over (N-M+1)} \\[5pt]
&=& {\sum_{k=1}^{M+1} k^\overline{N-M+1}\over (N-M+1)} \\[5pt]
&=& {(M+1)^\overline{N-M+2}\over (N-M+1)(N-M+2)}.\tag1 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

---

Assume that $j$ and $m$ are positive integers and that "sel" is $j/m$. Writing $s$ for "sel",
your expression is $$\sum_{x=0}^{m(1-s)} {(m-1-x)!\over (m(1-s)-x)!}(x+1)\cdot ms\,(m(1-s))! \tag2$$
Setting $N=m-1$ and $M=m(1-s)=m-j$  in (1), we see that (2) reduces to 
$$ {(m-j+1)^\overline{j+1}\over (ms)(ms+1)}\cdot ms\,(m-j)!={(m+1)!\over ms+1},$$
as you expected.